# How to display the number of running threads that I started in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I display the number of threads in an application that I started in the code ?

When I try `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count`, it will display me all running threads used by an application. I only need to count those ones that I started in the code using:

```
Thread t = new Thread(mymethod);
t.Start();
```

Comment: If you start them, why don't you count them?

Comment: `List<Thread> managedThreads = new List<Thread>(); managedThreads.Add(t); managedThreads.Count();`

Comment: in the meantime.. some of them may stop running.. I only need to get the number of RUNNING ones :)

Comment: managed.Threads.Count(thread => thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also consider structuring them so that they tell the parent when they get done.  That might also have benefits for managing them above and beyond just knowing how many are running.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't really understand which threads "you" created vs. ones you didn't.  I'm not sure I do either.  If your code calls some function that causes a thread to be created, is that you or someone else?  Hint "Thread t = new Thread(mymethod)" is a call to a function (the constructor) that causes a thread to be created.

I've also noticed that many C# programs (maybe all?) have more than the 1 thread I am expecting.  I don't know why all of them exist.

KC